# Ввод значения для параметра в post запросе

Tags: python

Я отправляю запрос с своим значением параметра, но  в итоге userId не присваивается.
хотя все выполняется, но вывод не тот который должен быть.
В чем проблема?

```
import requests
import pprint

url = "example.com"
    
userId = input ("Enter user id: ")

querystring = {"param":"{\"content\":\"userId\"}"}

headers = {
    'local': 'Ru',
}

response = requests.request("POST", url, headers=headers,  params=querystring)
pprint.pprint(response.json())
```

Comment: И где у вас используется переменная userId?

Comment: @СергейШ querystring = {"param":"{\"content\":\"      userId   \"}"}

Comment: вместо введенного значения через input, так и отправляется "userId"

Comment: Я вот не вишу что вы в этом коде querystring = {"param":"{\"content\":\" userId \"}"} используете переменную userId

Comment: пробовал ее указать убирая ковычки с "userId" {"param":"{\"content\":\userId \}"}, похоже это неправильно..

Comment: querystring = {"param":"{\"content\":\"переменная\"}"}  они имеюти такой вид.   если указать значение сразу, запрос проходит правильно.

Comment: userId = '12345' querystring = {"param": '{\"content\":\"' + userId + '\"}'} проверяем print(querystring['param']) вывод {"content":"12345"} как type str

Comment: Работает, спасибо

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Чтобы было немного проще:

- используйте два вида кавычек, тогда внутренние кавычки не нужно будет экранировать
- используйте `f-строки`, чтобы не складывать строки, правда из-за этого придётся экранировать уже фигурные скобки (их повторением)

```py
querystring = {'param': f'{{"content":"{userId}"}}'}
```

И да, вам нужно вывести саму переменную `userId`, окружив её строковыми кавычками. А сейчас вы выводите просто строку `"userId"`.